# rails polymorphic associations how do id and type get passed to the controller and inserted into a new record

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My profiles model has_many pictures through :imageable.
My picures model belongs_to profile, polymorphic: true.
So now i have a link to new_user_profile_pictures_path(current_user.id, current_user.profile.id), it creates a form that has these values now in the @picture object. 
I can put the imageable_type as a hidden field in the form because i know it's value is gonna be "profile", but what about imageable_id that i added to my model? How am i gonna get the value of that?
When I create a new picture, without using any hidden fields, the values of imageable_id and imageable_type are both null.

Comment: If you at least showed minimal effort and formatted your question...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to provide `imageable_type` and `imageable_id` any way. These fields will be automatically updated with the associated model instance.

**Profile model**

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pictures, as: :imageable
end
```

**Picture model**

```
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true
end
```

You can test your code on `rails console`

```
 > profile = Profile.create(name: "Fugee Ohu")
=> <Profile id: 1, name: "Fugee Ohu", created_at: "2016-01-23 04:26:44", updated_at: "2016-01-23 04:26:44">
```

Create a new `picture` instance with `profile` object. This new `picture` instance will have initiated `imageable_type` and 'imageable_id`based on their parent`profile`.

```
 > picture = profile.pictures.new
=> <Picture id: nil, name: nil, imageable_id: 1, imageable_type: "Profile", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

**Implement in your rails app**

According to your given `path` that is `new_user_profile_pictures_path(current_user.id, current_user.profile.id)`, you have `nested routes` for `pictures`

**In PicturesController**

```
def new
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  @profile = Profile.find(params[:profile_id])
  @picture = @profile.pictures.new
end

def create
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  @profile = Profile.find(params[:profile_id])
  @picture = @profile.pictures.new(pictures_params)
  respond_to do |format|
    if @picture.save
      format.html { redirect_to user_profile_path(@user, @profile), notice: 'Picture was successfully created.' }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
    end
  end
end
```

I hope this would be helpfull